# ionic/angular issue: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an application on ionic and getting the following issue. I am unable to resolve it.

```
MyApp.html:15 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.es5.js:7083)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.es5.js:1699)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10818)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12238)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12177)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12880)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12821)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyApp.html:16)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12806)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12144)
```

Following is the screenshot of the issue:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApO52Imsl0YIg_8G3pvovhPPr4wF0A

Please help.

Regards
Aman

Comment: what is the content in `MyApp.html:15`

Comment: Welcome to SO, You should share your code here so that others can help you to solve the issue. please have a tour  `https://stackoverflow.com/tour`.

Comment: Can you show to us the `MyApp.html` especially at line `15` then we can help you and please share a piece of code with us.

Comment: Your link is **not** a screenshot. If you want to add image to your post - use `<img src="[link for image file]"></img>`

Answer (score 0):

This error you are using iteration in object... IN ionic iteration performed only **array**